# Did Chomsky made the first generalization of coordination?

Tags: english, history, chomsky, coordination

If not then who? 
And maybe someone can suggest a good book of history of English linguistics? Can't find myself. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you could explain what **you** mean by "generalization of coordination", it might be possible to answer your question. However, without context, the phrase means next to nothing.

Comment: @jlawler the OP is asking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics) and Chomsky's work in generalizing it is touched on here https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6211/2345148915184e543be80864e24ad3c5d682.pdf I believe OP is asking if (Chomsky 1957) is the first example of someone making this generalization.

Comment: @Not_Here: So, conjunction reduction. Thank you. I certainly know of no earlier discussion.